# passing command line argument in c as parameters

Tags: function, struct, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to make a function to assign a structure members a value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct 
{
   int id;
   char *data;
}person_t;

person_t person_build(int id, char *data);


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
     person_t person = person_build(atoi(argv[1]), argv[2]);
     return 0;
}

person_t person_build(int id, char *data)
{
    person_t person;
    person.id = id;
    strcpy(person.data, data);

    return person;
}
```

This program compiled successfully.

I run that program and give command line arguments as parameters
to `person_build()` function as parameters.

```
>struct5.exe 4 Something
```

operating system(windows 7) give me a warning `this program has stopped working`

but when run without any command line argument (changing the `person_build()` parameter other than command line arguments) that program works.

can someone explain why this behaviour happen?

Answer (score 0):

Your program is not working because you are accessing memory structures that you have not initialized.  Specifically:

```
typedef struct 
{
   int id;
   char *data;
}person_t;
```

This creates a structure that has a `char *` as a member.  That `char *` allocates no actual memory, it simply reserves a member in the structure that can hold a memory address that should point to a value.  Later, you:

```
strcpy(person.data, data);
```

You are now copying data into the memory location that `person.data` points at even though you have never allocated memory or initialized `person.data`.

You could take this approach:

```
person_t person_build(int id, char *data)
{
    person_t person;
    person.id = id;
    person.data = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(data) + 1);
    if(person.data != NULL) strcpy(person.data, data);
    return person;
}
```

This allocates memory of the proper size, accounting for null termination at the end of the string, verifies that the allocation was successful and only then will it attempt to copy into that memory.

This is far from complete.  I think you may have many more obstacles yet to overcome!